# Convert GMT datetime string to utc epoch in 1000s of large csv files

Tags: perl, csv, datetime, utc

I have 1000s of csv files that consist of millions of rows that have integers, floats, nullable integers, and 2 types of GMT datetime string formats. Below is an example of such a row in one of the files:

`2/20/2016 3:25,3,,87,340.3456,5/18/2013,5/19/2014,4,6`

I'm interested in the quickest way to convert (in place) both types of GMT datetime formatted strings into UTC epochs.

For example, the above row would be converted into:

`1455938740,3,,87,340.3456,1368835200,1400457600,4,6`

Suppose the files are isolated, so all can be gathered by `*.csv`

Is there a way I could do this with linux commands? If not, what would you suggest then?

Comment: The `3:25` worries me. Do you suddenly sprout `PM` strings in the afternoon, or is it 24hr clock?

Comment: It's a 24 hour clock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

With thanks to @Borodin's insights, my best solution would now be like this:

```
perl -MTime::Local -plne '
   s|(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+) (\d+):(\d+)|timegm(0,$5,$4,$2,$1-1,$3)|ge ;
   s|(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)|timegm(0,0,0,$2,$1-1,$3)|ge' file.csv
```

And if that can be debugged and found to work, I would incorporate it into **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
function doit(){
    tmp=temp_$$
    perl -MTime::Local -plne '
       s|(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+) (\d+):(\d+)|timegm(0,$5,$4,$2,$1-1,$3)|ge;
       s|(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)|timegm(0,0,0,$2,$1-1,$3)|ge' "$1" >> $tmp && mv $tmp "$1"
}
export -f doit

find . -name \*.csv -print0 | parallel -0 doit {}
```

**Original Answer**

I'm afraid I am going to give you a very powerful fishing rod (more of a harpoon) rather than a ready-cooked fish supper, but I think you'll be able to work it out quite easily.

First, if you use the `Time::Local` module in Perl, you can pass it the seconds, minutes, hours, days, months and year and it will tell you the corresponding Epoch seconds:

```
# So, for midnight on 02:10:01 AM 1st May 2016, you can do
perl -MTime::Local -e 'print timelocal(1,10,2,1,5,2016)'
1464743401
```

Second, if you start Perl with `-plne` switches, it will effectively apply the code you supply to each and every line of the input file and print the result and sort out all line endings for you - somewhat akin to how `awk` loops over input files. So, if your file is called `file.csv` and looks like this:

```
2/20/2016 3:25,3,,87,340.3456,5/18/2013,5/19/2014,4,6
2/21/2013 3:25,3,,87,340.3456,4/20/2013,6/20/2015,4,6
```

and you run a null program, it will just echo the input file:

```
perl -MTime::Local -plne '' file.csv
2/20/2016 3:25,3,,87,340.3456,5/18/2013,5/19/2014,4,6
2/21/2013 3:25,3,,87,340.3456,4/20/2013,6/20/2015,4,6
```

If we now do a substitution and replace all commas with elephants:

```
perl -MTime::Local -plne 's/,/elephant/g' file.csv
2/20/2016 3:25elephant3elephantelephant87elephant340.3456elephant5/18/2013elephant5/1      9/2014elephant4elephant6
2/21/2013 3:25elephant3elephantelephant87elephant340.3456elephant4/20/2013elephant6/20/2015elephant4elephant6
```

That seems to work - now you can also do what I call a *"computed replacement"* - I don't know what real Perl-folk call it. Anyway, you use an `e` modifier flag after the replacement to execute that code and calculate the replacement text:

```
perl -MTime::Local -plne 's|(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)|timelocal(0,0,0,$2,$1,$3)|ge' file.csv
1458432000 3:25,3,,87,340.3456,1371510000,1403132400,4,6
1363824000 3:25,3,,87,340.3456,1369004400,1437346800,4,6
```

And - in case you missed it - that is the answer. The `(\d+)` is a regex for "one or more digits" and the fact it is in parentheses means it is captured. The first such group is captured as `$1`, the second as `$2` and so on. So, I am basically looking for one or more digits that I save as `$1`, followed by a slash then 1 or more digits that I capture as $2 followed by a slash and 1 or more digits that I capture as $3. Then, in the replacement part, I use the captured groups to formulate a date. The `g` modifier means I do ALL occurrences on each line.

I'll leave you to add further capture groups for the 24-hour time and put that into the `timelocal()` call.

The capture groups I have given are a little loose too - you may want

```
\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}
```

or something to mean 1 or 2 digits for the day, 1 or 2 digits for the month and exactly 4 digits for the year. You can look that up!

When you get that working, if you have thousands of files, I would suggest you use **GNU Parallel** to do the files in parallel. Try looking at my other answers on here, or Ole Tange's as he wrote it, and you will see something like:

```
function doit(){
    perl -plne '...' $1 ...
}
export -f doit

find . -name \*.csv -print0 | parallel -0 doit {}
```

As regards doing it in place, I think you will need to use a technique like this inside the `doit()` function. Basically it writes a new file and then, only if the `Perl` part worked (`&&` does that bit), it overwrites the original file with the temporary one:

```
tmp=$(mktemp ...)
perl -plne '...' "$1" > $tmp && mv $tmp "$1"
```

I suggest you make a backup before you do anything else - there is a lot to go wrong here. Good luck!

P.S. If you edit the tags under your question and add `perl`, I guess some Perl guru will help you out and maybe put the finishing touches on my suggestions and enlighten me/us as to what the real name is for the `e` modifier that does a *"computed replacement"*.

Comment: There isn't much in that answer that's directly relevant to the question! You will also need to use `timegm` instead of `timelocal` as the OP wants UTC time

Comment: @Borodin Thank you for sharing your experience. What is the proper name for the *"computed replacement"* please?

Comment: I don't know of a popular name for it. I call it an *executable substitution* or something similar. If the replacement string is executable code I generally use braces as delimiters to emphasize the fact, like `s{(.*)}{ '-' x length $1 }e` but there is also the `/ee` modifier, which means the replacement string is first executed, and then the return value from that is compiled and executed at run time as a tiny Perl program. It would be nice to have proper labels for these notions but I'm afraid they don't exist

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

As [*hinted by* Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36966031/622310) the `timegm` function from [`Time::Local`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Local) is likely to be faster than the string parsing that `Time::Piece` provides

Here's a rewrite of my original solution which uses that module. The output is identical to that of the original

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Time::Local 'timegm';

while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;

    my @fields = split /,/;

    for ( @fields ) {
        next unless m{/};

        my ($mn, $dy, $yr, $h, $m, $s) = (/\d+/g, 0, 0, 0);

        $_ = timegm($s, $m, $h, $dy, $mn-1, $yr);
    }

    print join(',', @fields), "\n";
}

__DATA__
2/20/2016 3:25,3,,87,340.3456,5/18/2013,5/19/2014,4,6
```

#### output

```
1455938700,3,,87,340.3456,1368835200,1400457600,4,6
```

---

#### Original post

The [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module is small and quite fast. Here's a sample program that transforms your sample data

The algorithm is a simple one. Any field that doesn't contain a slash `/` is left alone, otherwise it is assumed to be a date/time field if there is also a colon `:` or just a date field if not

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Time::Piece ();

while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;

    my @fields = split /,/;

    for ( @fields ) {
        next unless m{/};

        my $fmt = /:/ ? '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M' : '%m/%d/%Y';
        $_ = Time::Piece->strptime($_, $fmt)->epoch;
    }

    print join(',', @fields), "\n";
}

__DATA__
2/20/2016 3:25,3,,87,340.3456,5/18/2013,5/19/2014,4,6
```

#### output

```
1455938700,3,,87,340.3456,1368835200,1400457600,4,6
```

The first field `1455938700` differs from your own expect output `1455938740` by forty seconds. That's odd, as there is no seconds value in the original data and 1455938700 is exactly divisible by 60 whereas 1455938740 is not. So I stand by my computation

Comment: Nice - very elegant!